# MVC Global Method Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to block every request that contains unknown parameter.

for example,

**localhost/application/Home/Index** Or

**localhost/application/Home/Index?Module=Admin**

will give access to my Index page.

but a request should be block that contains unknown parameters like,

**localhost/application/Home/Index/?fakeParam=%24{76428%2b66104%2b%27f60cec015d33e6f70fc90789dd6659ff6b83da4d49f58d1fb7d1f0ae210ff7a8de500d534018c03aa77a440178e47b9e9dc66b53afa119163810502c2d1946f2%27}**

Right now this query also allows user to access my index page.

**What I did?**

I tried to get request and block it by their parameters at method level, but i think it's not easy to do for whole application.

Can I create one filter that check for request and if it finds any unknown parameter, request will be redirected to generic error page.

any help or idea will be appreciated?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Where do you see the potential risk? There might be a better method to do that.

Comment: @thomashaid.com: can you give me example of that methods/

Comment: It depends of what your security concerns are. In your eyes, what could happen to the application if you don't filter them out?

Comment: well, simply my client thinks it's a security breach..

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new action filter and apply it to the controller. Here is a rough outline for you.

Also see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.98).aspx
and: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx

So:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyQuerystringFilterAttribute()); //Add this
}
```

Then, add a new class:

```
public class MyQuerystringFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    //fires before the action is executed
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext 
filterContext)
    {
        // The action filter logic checking querystring and blocking if necessary
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller (on the controller level *or* action by action:

```
[MyQuerystringFilter]
public ActionResult Home() {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Bharat great - let me know how you get on